# Mirror modifier Not Working With the Skin Modifier

Tags: mesh, mirror

Whenever I create base meshes to sculpt on with the skin modifier, I add the mirror modifier but it always gives unexplainable results on the back portion of the mesh. I have tried playing with the root vertex but no luck.[image]

[image]

Comment: delete any faces where the Mirror merges, so there is empty space inside the Mesh and not two connecting faces.

Comment: How do you do that when you can only select vertices(Skin modifier)?

Comment: If you do not have a base mesh (with faces) then you may need to Apply the Mirror modifier before using the Skin modifier and remove duplicate vertices, this will, obviously break the non-destructive work flow.